# Should I use the "variation of parameters" here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand how I should approach this kind of equation. $${x^2\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)+6\cdot x\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\right)+6\cdot y}={\frac{x+4}{x^3-4\cdot x^2}}$$ $x>4$

I think I should use the "Variation of parameters" technique but for that I have to get at least one homogenous solution but I do not know how I should handle high order differential equation with none constant coefficients.

Comment: Interesting observation is that the powers of $x$ in LHS terms match the degree of the derivatives. Perhaps we could make a clever substitution to rewrite this into something like $$u'' + au' + bu'' = f(u)$$ and solve the usual linear 2nd order ODE? Unsuccessfully trying to find the substitution though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$${x^2\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)+6\cdot x\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\right)+6\cdot y}={\frac{x+4}{x^3-4\cdot x^2}}$$
It's [Cauchy-Euler's Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) .

Try $y=x^m$ for the homogeneous DE.

---

**Another way:**

You can also try this
$${x^4\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}\right)+6\cdot x^3\cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\right)+6x^2\cdot y}={\frac{x+4}{x-4}}$$
And integrate directly since you have that:
$$(x^4y')'+(2x^3y)'={\frac{x+4}{x-4}}$$
I think this method is easier than the variation of parameters. Integration gives us:
$$x^4y'+2x^3y=x+C_1 +8\ln |{x-4}|$$
It's a first order DE now.
$$(x^2y)'=\dfrac 1 x+ \dfrac {C_1}{x^2} +8\dfrac {\ln |{x-4}|}{x^2}$$
Integrate again if it's possible.

Comment: If I decide to solve it in your first method , with euler equation. after I found the homo solution, how should I find the private solution?

Comment: First solve the homogeneous DE and find the value of $m$ .Plug $y=x^m$ in the homogeneous DE...Then use the method of variation of parameters for the particular solution. @Sagigever

Comment: I found the solution for the homogenous DE, I do not understand why I should write constant as a coefficient of $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: Thats what its meant by variation of parameters you consider the constant as function of the variable. @Sagigever . If you apply the formulas you need to evaluate two integrals. Yake a look at the wiki page on the method of variation of parameters.